# Why is the range of signed char -127 to 127 in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was reading through *The C++ Programing language 4th Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup* and i was not able to fully understand the following paragraph mentioned in Page 141.

> Each character has an integer value in the character set used by the  implementation. For example,
>   the value of 'b' is 98 in the ASCII character set. Here is a loop that outputs the the integer value
>   of any character you care to input:

```
void intval()
{
    for (char c; cin >> c; )
        cout << "the value of '" << c << "' is " << int{c} << '\n';
}
```

> The notation int{c} gives the integer value for a character c (‘‘the int we can construct from c’’).
>   The possibility of converting a char to an integer raises the question: is a char signed or unsigned?
>   The 256 values represented by an 8-bit byte can be interpreted as the values 0 to 255 or **as the values −127 to 127. No, not −128 to 127 as one might expect: the C++ standard leaves open the possibility of one’s-complement hardware** and that eliminates one value; thus, a use of −128 is nonportable.
>   Unfortunately, the choice of signed or unsigned for a plain char is implementation defined.
>   C++ provides two types for which the answer is definite: signed char, which can hold at least the values −127 to 127, and unsigned char, which can hold at least the values 0 to 255.

What is the possibility of one's complement hardware that c++ standard leaves? Is it to avoid the same representation of +128 and -128 in 8 bit?

Comment: have you looked up what one's-complement **is**? :/

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, as one's complement is more lower level and suited toward actual machine implementation or architecture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An 8 bit signed integer using one's complement representation can only have values from -127 to -0 and from +0 to +127. That's because there are two ways to represent zero; a positive zero and a negative zero.

Same with signed magnitude representation.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to [represent signed numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), and which method is used is dictated by the hardware of arithmetic unit of the CPU. Although the 2's complement representation has become dominant, C and C++ still make it a point that old hardware that uses different representations must be supported.

Note that a `signed char` may have a much wider range, such as –2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup> – 1, if byte is 32-bit on a particular architecture. –127 to 127 is the minimum minimorum that any compliant implementation is required to permit.

Comment: Byte and `char` are different things. Byte is traditionally 8 bits, whereas `char` could be anything,

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, but in C/C++ parlance, byte and char are essentially the same thing. Specifications for network protocols use the term 'octet' to avoid any ambiguity.